# Is "bump into their conversation" a correct sentence to express getting into others conversation unexpectedly?

Tags: word-choice

Is "bump into their conversation" a correct sentence to express getting into others conversation unexpectedly ?

Comment: People use 'jump' in that way, like when interrupting, using, 'can I jump right in for a moment here?'

Answer (score 1):

Try

**barge into** ([TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/barge+into))

> 1. To abruptly and/or rudely interrupt or intrude on someone or something without warning.

as in:

> *My bedroom is a private place, you can't just barge in like that!*
>   
>   *John thought he'd found the door to the restroom, but he accidentally barged into the board meeting instead.*

Answer (score 0):

**Fall into**

> [fall into something] to start doing something by chance
>
> fall into conversation to start having a conversation with someone, especially someone you have just met

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/fall-into

I would say that he fell into their conversation, not bumped into the conversation. The latter is not idiomatic.

Bumped into person is idiomatic for meeting someone unexpectedly and can include a conversation, but the sentence would be “I bumped into Alice and Bob,” not “I bumped into their conversation.” You could say something like “I was at the next table and fell into their conversation.”

> [bump into someone] to meet someone unexpectedly
>
> *I bumped into your mother at the supermarket.*

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/bump-into